# Stop Specific tests from running in parallel, but only with eachother

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit

I am writing tests in Selenium using NUnit. 
I am running the tests in Firefox, Chrome and IE. as such:

```
    [TestFixture(typeof(ChromeDriver))]
    [TestFixture(typeof(FirefoxDriver))]
    [TestFixture(typeof(InternetExplorerDriver))]
    [Parallelizable]   
    class ProgramTests<TWebDriver> where TWebDriver : IWebDriver, new()
    { 
        [tests in here] 
    }
```

The issue i am having is that one of my tests changes some options that are external to the web instance.
Meaning if this test runs in IE and Chrome then starts the test, one can change the settings while the other is checking them, messing up the tests.

If i use the NonParallelizable attribute, the tests will just execute one by one, once all the parallel ones are done.

Is there any way to make the tests parallelized, but just not with each other?

Answer (score 0):

`[Parallelizable]` is shorthand for `[Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Self)]`.

When you use it on a `TestFixture` it means that fixture can run in parallel with other fixtures. If the fixture is parameterized, as yours is, the instances for each driver can run in parallel with one another as well as with any other fixtures. The test methods under the fixture default to non-parallelizable.

For the test methods to be parallelizable, you can use separate attributes on each method or you can specify the scope of parallelization at the fixture level. On the `TestFixture`, you have the following options.

- `[Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Self)]` works as described above.
- `[Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Children)]` causes the fixture to be non-parallelizable but allows all the tests to run in parallel with one another.
- `[Parallelizable(ParallelScope.All)]` allows both the fixture and the test methods to run in parallel.

In deciding which way to go, it's important to remember that the `ParallelizableAttribute` doesn't **make** your tests capable of running in parallel, it merely **promises** NUnit that it's OK to run them that way.

In particular, it's usually not possible to run test cases that use the same Selenium driver in parallel because each test will change the state of the driver in ways that surprise the other tests that are running!

Comment: All the tests run and work fine in parallel, all of the used drivers are different instances and all the functions used are non static.
The only thing stopping them from running parallel is the thing the tests are testing.
I just want to know how to stop them from running parallel with each other but not the other tests